# Win32: Can't Show window after hide it?

Tags: winapi, hide, showwindow

I was trying to show a window using `ShowWindow` in a Callback function that called is set by a `SetTime` after I have hided it, but it didn't worked.
Please check the following code example.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include<windows.h>
void CALLBACK f(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"Test","test2",MB_OK);
    ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_SHOW );  //This will not show the window :(
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"Is it shown?","test2",MB_OK);
}
int main()
{
    MSG msg;
    ShowWindow( GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE );
    SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000*3, &f);
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you cast `f`? Remove that cast. You don't check for errors. Why not?

Comment: Pretty impossible to tell, what *"doesn't work"*. The text says, you cannot show a window, after it was hidden. The code says something else (`ShowWindow(hwnd, SW_SHOW); //won't hide the window`). I don't know, why you opted for the wrong [TimerProc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644907.aspx) signature either.

Comment: Why don't you set a breakpoint on your `ShowWindow`-call (inside `f`), and observe the value of `hwnd`? Since the timer is not associated with a window, I'd assume it is `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

As @IInspectable suggested, it is the wrong handle that the call back function carries (which is the handle `NULL` which have been passed to `SetTimer`).

To correct the code above, you should use the same handle for both **show** and **hide**.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#include<windows.h>
HWND hwnd;
void CALLBACK f(HWND __hwnd__, UINT uMsg, UINT timerId, DWORD dwTime)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"Test","test2",MB_OK);
    ShowWindow( hwnd, SW_SHOW );  //This will not show the window :(
    MessageBoxA(NULL,"Is it shown?","test2",MB_OK);
}
int main()
{
    MSG msg;
    hwnd=GetConsoleWindow();

    ShowWindow(hwnd , SW_HIDE );

    SetTimer(NULL, 0, 1000*3, &f);
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you.